# Slokas to be recited at the end of SriVaishnava Thiruvarradanam

Tags: sri-vaishnava

I have heard set of verses from each vedha, Ramayana slokas, Gita slokas being recited at the end of SriVaishnava thiruvaaraadhanam. These are only selected slokas or verses and not full text of the granthas.
I am eager to learn this but could not find it by searching the net.
Can someone help with these slokas please

Comment: are they the ekshloki ramayana etc?

Comment: Not ekasloki Ramayana
I mean starting verses from Valmiki Ramayana and Bhagavad Gita

Comment: nitya karm puja prakash by gita press has some set of similar shlokas you may want to look at that, pdf is there on archive